# Setting a max JSON response size limit

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, express, nginx

We have a public REST API on nodejs, where we allow our clients to make query to our endpoints. The clients can add additional query parameters to fetch more connected/related data.

Recently, we planned on setting a JSON response limit on our APIs.

Possible solutions:

- `Buffer.byteLength(data, 'utf-8')`
- `JSON.stringify(data).length`

Is it possible to limit the response size from the Nginx OR from AWS?
What is the correct way to handle the response size limit?

Comment: Are you using express or which framework on nodejs backend?

Comment: Yes, currently using express

Answer (score 1):

For request limits, you would use `app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb" }));`

As for responses, there is no size limit on responses sent from a node HTTP server. The amount of memory your application has access to is the only limitation.

Comment: The objective is to find a way to apply limitations on the response being returned to our clients.

Comment: Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-response-size, hopefully that can help you.